# Returned result is false with numpy conditions

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a little script in order to return a list of 'characters' from a list of values :

List of values :

```
11
11
14
6
6
14
```

My script :

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/produit.txt',
                  dtype = int)


taille = len(data)

for j in range (0, taille) :

    if data[j] == 1 or 2 or 3 or 11 or 12 or 13 :
        print 'cotisation'

    if data[j] == 14 :
        print 'donation'

    else :
        print 'part'
```

What I need to get :

```
'cotisation'
'cotisation'
'donation'
'part'
'part'
'donation'
```

What I get :

```
cotisation
part
cotisation
part
cotisation
donation
```

I don't see where I made an error ..
If someone could read my script and maybe correct him ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for j in range(0, taille):
    if data[j] in {1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13}:
        print ("cotisation")
    elif data[j] == 14:
        print ("donation")
    else:
        print ("part")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues here:

### `if x == 1 or 2 or 3 or ...` does not do what you are expecting.

Each clause is evaluated independently, so python does not know you are implying `if x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3`, etc.  It instead interprets this as `if x == 1` or `if 2` or `if 3` ...  `if 2` and the like is actually a sensical if statement in python and is basically tantamount to asking `if True` (all non-zero integer values have a "truthiness" of True).  So your statement is really equivalent to `if data[j] == 1 or True or True or True or True`, which reduces to `if True`.  In other words, the condition is always satisfied regardless of the value.  What you probably meant was:

```
if data[j] == 1 or data[j] == 2 or data[j] == 3 or data[j] == 11 ...
```

### Your if-else construction has two blocks when one is intended

Currently boils down to something like the following in pseudocode:

```
if some condition:
    print 'something'

now regardless of the first condition, if some other disjoint condition:
    print 'something else'
otherwise:
    print 'does not match other condition'
```

In other words, by using two ifs, the second if block, of which the `else` is a part, is treated as completely independent of the first if. So cases that satisfy the first condition could *also* satisfy the else, which is sounds like is not what you wanted as each character should print exactly once.  If you want it to be 3 disjoint cases, you need to use `elif` instead so it is all considered part of a single block:

E.g.

```
if condition:
    print 'something'
elif other condition:
    print 'something else'
else:
    print 'does not match EITHER of the two above condtions'
```

Answer (score 0):

Scimonster point out your 1st issue in the code, you need elif for the second if.

The 2nd issue is the or part, your if condition is being intepret as

```
 if (data[j] == 1) or 2 or 3 or 11 or 12 or 13
```

You could fixed them as below

```
if data[j] in [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13] :
    print 'cotisation'
elif data[j] == 14 :
    print 'donation'
else :
    print 'part'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if data[j] == 1 or 2 or 3 or 11 or 12 or 13 :
    print 'cotisation'

if data[j] == 14 :
    print 'donation'

else :
    print 'part'
```

You have two separate `if`s here, and one has an `else`. They should all flow together, so the second should be `elif`.

Comment: When I replace the second `if ` by `elif`, I'm only getting `cotisation`